# Cannot verify signature

Tags: solidity, remix, signature, keccak, ecrecover

I have been trying to do it but it always return me false, tried a lot of ways but I don't know.
Here is the smart contract

```
function _verify(
        bytes32 hashedMessage,
        bytes memory signature
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        require(signature.length == 65, "Invalid Signature");
        bytes32 ethHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hashedMessage));
        (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) = _split(signature);
        return ecrecover(ethHash, v, r, s) == owner;
    }

    function _split(bytes memory signature) internal pure returns (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) {
        assembly {
            r := mload(add(signature, 32))
            s := mload(add(signature, 64))
            v := byte(0, mload(add(signature, 96)))
        }
    }
```

Here is the typescript code where I am getting the result

```
    async mintNFT(tokenId: number): Promise<any> {
        const hashedMesage = keccak256(toUtf8Bytes(tokenId.toString()));
        const wallet = new Wallet(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_KEY as string);
        const signature = await wallet.signMessage((hashedMesage));
        return this.sendContract.getFunction('_verify')(hashedMesage, signature)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
            return 'error'
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you did not need this line

```
bytes32 ethHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hashedMessage));
```

because when you sign the message with ethers, it already adds it to the hash.